# ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mymbp.pid)

Tags: mysql, xampp

I get this ERROR when I try to start the mysql server with command line. I have been all over here looking for a solution but it seems everyone is different. I started mysql by using this command:

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
./mysql.server start
```

These commands worked fine while I was at my school, but when I try these exact same commands at my home I get the error mentioned. Any ideas?

Using macbook pro 10.9.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did it:

I started mysql from terminal with the following two lines,

cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin

./mysql.server start

Then it is highly possible I did not stop it and it kept running and I would get the ERROR! mentioned. Then I did the following,

To "kill" a process using Terminal:

- Run Terminal
- Type top, and then, press Enter
- From the results, the first column provides the processes' Process ID (PID) number.
- Note the PID of the process you want to kill.
- Type q, and then, press Enter to quit top.
- Type sudo kill PID, and then, press Enter where PID is the value you got from top.

I found a process called mysqld 34630 and did sudo kill 34630
Then I restarted mysql with the two lines above I started with. Then it worked. Just remember to stop it when finished!!

Answer (score 1):

Might be some backward compatibility issue.
Try Backing up and Removing the SQL config file (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf) 
and restart the mySQL Server.

Comment: You should be more specific in your answer.

Comment: @harishchakravarthy That's it there are no other steps involved?

Comment: @harishchakravarthy You say back up, what is the risk of not backing up? What could be lost?

Comment: the config file may not work if u have used previous versions or a different version of mysql before your current version on the system. it worked for me, i will work on the scenario though !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, adding a "sudo" worked for me:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

Comment: yes I recall having to use that method as well! Thanks!